# Django: Missing tables for profiles when converting to Postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a problem that I hope someone with insight can aid with. My first Django project is near completion and I’m currently transitioning to a Postgres database in anticipation of deploying via Heroku. The process was going fairly smoothly until this occurred when I ran python manage.py syncdb.

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation “report_userprofile” does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO “report_userprofile” (“user_id”, “first_name”, “…
```

Apparently, it did not create DB tables for the UserProfile model. I’m now getting this exception when I attempt to run the server:

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Among the additional apps I'm using for the project is django-profiles, which I had some issues setting up which are apparently common. The "Missing Manual" site – http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/ – helped resolve those but may have led to the current problem.

I am using the signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User) recommended there. I was researching what might have gone wrong and came across this post on Google Groups and answer which states that “If you’re using a post_save signal on User you can’t do that because it results in a race condition." I’m wondering if this may be causing the issue and, obviously, what would be best to resolve it and get these tables into the new database and functioning.

Any insight into how to remedy this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This is the database model that may be causing the problem:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name="profile")
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
email = models.EmailField()
birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepictures', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return " %s" % (self.user)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('profiles_profile_detail', (), { 'username': self.user.username })
get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something seems suspicious here:

```
INSERT INTO “report_userprofile” (“user_id”, “first_name”, “…
```

Those two fields are fields on the native User model, not fields on the custom Profile model. Why would it be trying to insert those fields into your Profile table?

Is there more code you're not showin here?

Looking around, I see some interesting alternative approaches to automatically creating Profile records:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/500/
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile

But I know that the technique you're using (listed at Birdhouse) has worked well for every Django site I've built, so I'm not particularly suspicious of that.